# Generalization of algorithms that can run in O(n) from O(n2) naive solution

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I'm doing some leetcode exercises and I'm wondering "why" some algorithm can run in O(n).
The exercise is that one : https://leetcode.com/problems/container-with-most-water/
The goal is to find the pair of bars (here in red) in a list, such that between these bars there is maximum 'water' volume if we filled the space between the bars with water:
[image]

This algorithm can be obviously solved in O(n2) by trying all pairs

There is however and algorithm to solve this problem in O(n):

- find out the surface between the 2 bars when they are at extreme positions
- at each step, either bring the left bar or the right bar closest to the other by 1 step (which one is chosen depends on the size of the bars)
- return the biggest surface amongst all the combinations that were tried

I've seen several other problems somewhat similar, where the obvious solution in O(n2) can be improved to linear time by only selecting some configurations in a "greedy" way at each step.
I'm wondering if there is any theory / generalization of this approach. Ie, what is the fundamental reason that this initial problem can be solved in O(n) ? Is there a way, from the problem definition, to ensure that it can be solved in O(n), without having to find out this particular trick?

Comment: *"Is there a way, from the problem definition, to ensure that it can be solved in O(n), without having to find out this particular trick?"* Nope, you learn a variety of different techniques as you gain experience. Then you need to decide which technique applies to the problem you're trying to solve. The technique used here is a two-pointer meet-in-the-middle approach. Well known examples that use this  approach are binary search, and the partition step in a quick sort.

Comment: @user3386109
thanks
here the problem I have isn't really to "think about" using this approach (with enough experience I see how I could have thought about it), but rather, understanding _why_ this approach will work, ie why checking only this specific subset of solutions is enough to find the optimmum

Comment: Ok, but there's nothing generalizable about that. It's just an analysis of the geometry of this particular problem. The amount of water is **width times height**. By starting at the two ends of the array, you **maximize the width**. Then the tradeoff is to **improve the height by reducing the width**.

Comment: The first step is to move the left bar, since that's a major improvement in height with only a minor reduction in width. The next step is to either move the left bar to improve the height (can't be done since there are no taller bars), or move the right bar to improve the height. You can do that, but the amount of water is reduced from 7x7 to 5x8. At that point, you're done since there are no taller bars.

Comment: BTW, there's a problem in your description of the algorithm. In the second step of the algorithm, it says *"either bring the left bar or the right bar closest to the other by 1 step"* If you do that, then the function is not convex. What you need to do is either improve the height of the shorter bar (when the bars are different heights), or improve the height of both bars (when the bars have equal height).

Comment: @user3386109 "Then the tradeoff is to improve the height by reducing the width." -> sure but that doesn't explain why this approach is working. As I said, you are only going through n combinations of bars, instead of n² possible. I know it's correct (as we can prove the algorithm is correct), but it's not clear to me exactly what makes this problem exactly solvable in that way. For instance, if we were trying to maximize width*max(height1, height2) instead of min, could this problem be solved the same way? etc

Comment: To answer your specific question, if you try to maximize `width * max(height1, height2)`, then the algorithm is different and simpler. More broadly, there is no general answer to all algorithm problems.

Comment: I totally relate to your question, about what makes some questions solvable in linear times and what makes others only doable in quadratic. This is an active area of research (complexity theory) and proofs are VERY difficult to come by; few lower bounds are known. A generalized theory, or philosophically satisfying fact is probably distant.